# Reshaping data to use for panel data studies, using tidyr or dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape, tidyr

I have a data frame, with 28 rows and 26 columns. Each column represents a day, and each row represents a time period `t`. It looks like this:

```
dput(head(training_data,10))
structure(list(X11950.0 = c(1L, 15L, 15L, 18L, 31L, 57L, 96L, 
134L, 235L, 291L), X11952.0 = c(0L, 15L, 11L, 18L, 45L, 76L, 
97L, 115L, 200L, 234L), X11955.0 = c(0L, 13L, 14L, 10L, 30L, 
49L, 86L, 114L, 193L, 239L), X11956.0 = c(0L, 15L, 10L, 8L, 38L, 
41L, 96L, 117L, 222L, 227L), X11957.0 = c(0L, 10L, 8L, 14L, 33L, 
61L, 84L, 143L, 211L, 249L), X11958.0 = c(0L, 18L, 14L, 16L, 
48L, 49L, 87L, 117L, 209L, 258L), X11959.0 = c(0L, 14L, 14L, 
17L, 33L, 57L, 93L, 100L, 189L, 241L), X11962.0 = c(0L, 8L, 8L, 
16L, 29L, 48L, 88L, 126L, 202L, 211L), X11963.0 = c(0L, 8L, 10L, 
14L, 44L, 51L, 98L, 148L, 228L, 218L), X11964.0 = c(0L, 15L, 
16L, 12L, 39L, 59L, 109L, 138L, 227L, 233L), X11965.0 = c(0L, 
14L, 13L, 18L, 34L, 46L, 89L, 154L, 199L, 264L), X11966.0 = c(0L, 
18L, 13L, 15L, 37L, 49L, 93L, 142L, 183L, 236L), X11969.0 = c(0L, 
7L, 10L, 15L, 34L, 34L, 84L, 136L, 206L, 233L), X11970.0 = c(0L, 
12L, 14L, 25L, 36L, 50L, 121L, 145L, 206L, 238L), X11971.0 = c(0L, 
17L, 8L, 20L, 36L, 47L, 92L, 108L, 144L, 147L), X12088.0 = c(0L, 
5L, 10L, 9L, 35L, 55L, 92L, 112L, 215L, 241L), X12089.0 = c(1L, 
8L, 10L, 15L, 15L, 0L, 46L, 118L, 221L, 241L), X12090.0 = c(0L, 
8L, 10L, 15L, 46L, 43L, 101L, 106L, 225L, 235L), X12091.0 = c(0L, 
5L, 13L, 19L, 40L, 40L, 80L, 119L, 214L, 208L), X12092.0 = c(0L, 
9L, 13L, 18L, 41L, 41L, 89L, 100L, 205L, 200L), X12095.0 = c(0L, 
8L, 13L, 6L, 32L, 55L, 69L, 112L, 199L, 202L), X12096.0 = c(0L, 
7L, 12L, 27L, 40L, 36L, 102L, 119L, 216L, 228L), X12097.0 = c(0L, 
9L, 15L, 14L, 43L, 51L, 94L, 122L, 220L, 231L), X12098.0 = c(0L, 
10L, 15L, 14L, 47L, 39L, 90L, 117L, 223L, 221L), X12099.0 = c(0L, 
9L, 13L, 16L, 39L, 52L, 94L, 110L, 220L, 216L), X12102.0 = c(0L, 
9L, 10L, 9L, 51L, 43L, 82L, 98L, 175L, 196L)), .Names = c("X11950.0", 
"X11952.0", "X11955.0", "X11956.0", "X11957.0", "X11958.0", "X11959.0", 
"X11962.0", "X11963.0", "X11964.0", "X11965.0", "X11966.0", "X11969.0", 
"X11970.0", "X11971.0", "X12088.0", "X12089.0", "X12090.0", "X12091.0", 
"X12092.0", "X12095.0", "X12096.0", "X12097.0", "X12098.0", "X12099.0", 
"X12102.0"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm trying to do regression analysis, regressing each time period in a given day on its previous 3 values. For that, I want to mung the data in a way that for each row, column 1 `yt` would contain the value for the time `t` and columns 2 to 4 would contain `y(t-1)` till `y(t-3)`.

My code so far is this:

```
a <- stack(training_data)[,1, drop=FALSE]
panel.data <- read.csv(text="indiv, t, yt, y.t.1, y.t.2, y.t.3", 
                   colClasses = c(integer(), integer(), integer(),
                                  integer(), integer(), integer()),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
for(block.id in (0: ((nrow(a)/28) -1))) {
  # day blocks
  block <- a[(28*(block.id)+1) : (28*(block.id+1)), ]
  yt <- block[4:28]
  first.time.period <- block[3:27]
  second.time.period <- block[2:26]
  third.time.period <- block[1:25]

  insert.block <- c((25*(block.id)+1) : (25*(block.id+1))) 
  panel.data[insert.block, ]$yt <- yt
  panel.data[insert.block, ]$y.t.1 <- first.time.period
  panel.data[insert.block, ]$y.t.2 <- second.time.period
  panel.data[insert.block, ]$y.t.3 <- third.time.period

}
```

Remember again that there are 28 time periods for each day.

This works, but it was a lot of struggle to make it, and it's ugly and not really reusable. For example, now I have another data set which looks like this but has different number of rows, and I want to join this table with another table, etc. It's a headache.

My question: Is there a way to do this, preferably with Hadley's packages (tidyr, dplyr) more cleanly? I've studied these two a bit, and maybe `spread()` would do it? I'm a beginner in those packages and even though I've tried for a few hours now I haven't been able to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution. I am assuming that you don't want to overlap days (ie. that t-1 for the first period of the second day should not be the last period of the first day). If this is not the case, just remove the `group_by()` statement. The `slice()` removes the first three periods of each day.

```
gather(df,day,y) %>% 
  group_by(day) %>% 
  mutate(t1=lag(y),
         t2=lag(t1),
         t3=lag(t2)) %>% 
  slice(-c(1:3))
```

Comment: Thanks, it work brilliantly! just a couple of points: 1) I probably should use lag instead of lead. 2) If I use lag, I need to discard, for each day, the first 3 rows of the resultant dataframe. I can definitely do it manually, just wanted to know your opinion

Comment: my bad, you should indeed use lag. I'll edit this. It will output NAs where it cannot find any preceding value. If you want to remove the first rows, you can use slice()